# Bootstrap 3.1 gradient less mixin error on IE8 and 9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, mixins

I have a problem with gradient mixin for ie8 and 9 browsers because the gradient mixin seems to have a little bug because the hexa code from gradien has to many characters resulted from bootstrap mixin. If someone encountred this problem and solved please share.
This is less mixin from bootstrap:

```
  .vertical(@start-color: #555; @end-color: #333; @start-percent: 0%; @end-percent: 100%) {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent);  // Safari 5.1-6, Chrome 10+
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, @start-color @start-percent, @end-color @end-percent); // Standard, IE10, Firefox 16+, Opera 12.10+, Safari 7+, Chrome 26+
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: e(%("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='%d', endColorstr='%d', GradientType=0)",argb(@start-color),argb(@end-color))); // IE9 and down
  }
```

variables:

```
@table-header1: rgba(155,214,45,0.65);
@table-header2: rgba(123,192,67,0.99);
```

less:

```
.table {
  thead tr {
     font-weight:normal;
     #gradient > .vertical(@table-header1 , @table-header2);
       th {
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
        color: @asf-table-th-color;
        border-color:#428BCA;
        border-width: 1px;
        font-weight:bold;
     }
   }
}
```

And this is the result from this mixin:

```
  .table thead tr {
      font-weight: normal;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(155, 214, 45, 0.65) 0%, rgba(123, 192, 67, 0.99) 100%);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(155, 214, 45, 0.65) 0%, rgba(123, 192, 67, 0.99) 100%);
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a69bd62d', endColorstr='#fc7bc043', GradientType=0);
     }
```

Now if you look carefully the hex code from ie filter gradient has to many characters.

this is an example of ie8 gradient with correct hex code:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example of the correct hex value is wrong, as you can see at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532930(v=vs.85).aspx StartColorStr should set to:

> Color is expressed in #AARRGGBB format, where AA is the alpha
>   hexadecimal value, RR is the red hexadecimal value, GG is the green
>   hexadecimal value, and BB is the blue hexadecimal value. The alpha
>   value controls the opacity of the object. An alpha value of 00 is
>   transparent, while a value of FF is opaque. String input that is
>   outside the hexadecimal range will revert to the default value (#FF0000FF).